# How to get current location at once and after it -load map?

Tags: android, google-maps, location, google-maps-android-api-2

i have next issue: i want to get current location after that i want to draw some markers around it. I have used `LocationListener` to get current location, but when i run my app i saw empty map and after few seconds i get current location and draw markers. I want to make next: I want to load map when after I get current location.I don't want to see map without markers. My code is:

```
public class WhereAmIFragment extends BaseContainerFragment implements LocationListener {
private SupportMapFragment mMapFragment;
private LocationManager locationManager;

public static WhereAmIFragment newInstance() {
    return new WhereAmIFragment();
}

private GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener mOnMapClickListener = new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
    }
};

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_where_am_i, container, false);
    mMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
    getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map_container, mMapFragment).commit();
    return root;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mMapFragment.getMap().setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mMapFragment.getMap().setOnMapClickListener(mOnMapClickListener);
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    locationManager.removeUpdates(WhereAmIFragment.this);
    locationManager = null;
    drawStops(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
}


private void drawStops(LatLng latLng) {
    DefaultCallback<ArrayList<Stop>> callback = new DefaultCallback<ArrayList<Stop>>(getActivity()) {
        @Override
        public void success(ArrayList<Stop> stops, Response response) {
            Log.d("myLogs", "array list size= " + stops.size());
            for (int i = 0; i < stops.size(); i++) {
                Log.d("myLogs", i + ". " + stops.get(i).getLng());
                drawMarkers(stops);
            }
        }
    };
    mMapFragment.getMap().moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 14.0f));
    RequestDataBuilder builder = new RequestDataBuilder(getActivity()).prepareWhereAmIData(
            latLng, 500);
    EwayApi api = RestAdaptersProvider.getApi(new StopsConverter());
    api.sendRequest(builder, callback);
}

private void drawMarkers(ArrayList<Stop> arrayList) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
        mMapFragment.getMap().addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(arrayList.get(i).getLng())
                .title(arrayList.get(i).getTitle()));
    }
}
@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

}
```

}

Comment: Try to do your location listener code in master activity instead of when you load map so you can directly access you location data at map load.

Answer (score 0):

the map can be init as,

```
SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
map = fm.getMap();
map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);         
map.setTrafficEnabled(true);
map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
```

You can add markers like,

```
LatLng toPosition = new LatLng(Promolat, Promolon);

             map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(toPosition)
                .title(promotions.getPromotionHeading().toString())
                .snippet(merchants.getMerchantAddress().toString())
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));

             map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(toPosition, 15));
```

Comment: how it can help me? Where i should initialize map?

Comment: Please, read my question again. I know how to get current location